# I want to insert data into a SQL Server databse using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to insert data into a SQL Server database using C#.

There is no error in my code. But after entering the data I traverse. It shows me the data. But when I open the database table. I can't see the inserted data. I initialize the table in the time of creation with 2 rows. But when I traverse through form I can't see those rows.

After so many trial an error. I see that database connection breaks down whenever I run it. I saw that the "green plug" on the database icon went to "red cross" after clicking F5. Is that the reason? If it is then what should be the solution ?

Guys please help me. I am new at C#.

This is `insert.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace employeDB1
{
public partial class Insert : Form
{
    public Insert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DatabaseConnection objConnect;
    string conString;
    int inc ;
    int MaxRows;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataRow dRow;

    public void Insert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeConnectionString;
            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
            objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;
            ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
            MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            inc = MaxRows - 1;
            //NavigateRecords();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            row[0] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            row[1] = textBox2.Text;
            row[2] = textBox3.Text;
            row[3] = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
        try
        {

            objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);
            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
            inc = MaxRows - 1;
            MessageBox.Show("RECORD INSERTED");

        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
        textBox1.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc>0)
        {
            inc--;
            NavigateRecords();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First Record");
        }
    }
 }
}
```

This is the database connection class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace employeDB1
{
class DatabaseConnection
{
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;

    public string Sql
    {
        set { sql_string = value; }
    }

    public string connection_string
    {
        set { strCon = value; }
    }

    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
    {
        get { return MyDataSet(); }
    }

    private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();
        return dat_set;
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap your C# in a try/catch block and examine the exception.  That should give you more information.

Comment: Most likely you are looking in the wrong place or at the wrong time for the data.  You are presumably either calling Update on a data adapter or ExecuteNonQuery on a command to modify the database. In that case there are three possible outcomes: changes are saved and the method returns a non-zero value, no changes are saved and the method returns zero or an exception is thrown. You say that there are no errors so it must be one of the first two. Which is it? Also, are you connecting to a database on a server or a local data file? I'm guessing that it's the latter.

Comment: please post your data access code

Comment: Are you using any Transaction In it

Comment: How do you setup the connection string? Are you using `ADO.Net`? Code man code?

Comment: please read this article and again check your code that how to insert data in database using asp.net http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/05/introduction-to-3-tier-architecture-in_17.html i thinks you have do miner mistake.

Comment: If you're using **C#** - then this is **NOT** `asp-classic`, but **ASP.NET** - updated your tags$

Comment: I have posted the code. plz guys tell me where I have done a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your connection string in a app.config file and then retrieve it or you can hard code it in your insert.cs file. I have checked it using app.config file and it was working. Here what I did.

> app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Server=192.168.8.295;Database=TestDB;
           uid=Tapan;pwd=kumar;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then just replace the thing you are retriving from settings in your insert.cs page

```
 conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
```

And remove this thing

```
 objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;
```

And check once if it is working or not. For me it was working.

Still if you have problem then first put try catch in your code and debug thoroughly first and see where your code is dying..